# AJAX email form validation in AJAX loaded div?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, alerts

I've created a pretty straight-forward site which loads all of its content via jquery `.load()` functions when you click the navigation links, and it works great. What I want now is to load in an email contact form with AJAX-style validation that alert the user about invalid input fields prior to running the php submission.

In other words, user clicks navigation link for "contact me" and a form is loaded into the content div. If the user enters an invalid name or email and hits submit, appropriate error messages will appear next to those input fields. I don't really care what happens after form goes through, whether it be a popup window or redirect page.

I've been trying to figure this out for weeks and I'm ready to give up. The form loads fine, but I can't figure out the basic construct for getting an AJAX loaded form to respond to the user without reloading the page and clearing their fields. I even got the php form submission part working exactly how I want, but getting client-side scripts to function with server-side php functions just seems arduous.

Is this even possible? How should I go about this? What are the basic concepts and tools for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my form to work using the jquery validation plugin! Thanks to Praveen for suggesting it. It's a great tool.

The underlying issue was that I really wasn't wrapping my head around .load(). Once I utilized the .load() callback function, the validation ran fine. I created an external javascript file called contact.js which contains the validation plugin rules and submitHandler nested within contactPageScript() function. I called contactPageScript() with the .load() callback and voila:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#menu ul li a").click(function() {
      var whichPage = $(this).attr('href');
      $('div#page_content').load(($(this).attr('href') + ' #contentB'), function(){
                    if (whichPage == 'contact.html') {
                        contactPageScript();
                    }}
      );
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
```

The validation script of course also worked fine nested within the callback function rather than as an external .js, but it was too lengthy for my tastes. And there were some small details to be worked out regarding the validation rules. Here's the chunk of validation code I used just for reference:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mailform').validate( { 
    rules: {
      fullname: {
        required: true,
        minlength:2
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      fullname: 'Please enter a valid name',
      email: 'Please enter a valid email address'
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       $.post('php/submitForm.php', $('#mailform').serialize(), function() { DO STUFF });
    }
  });
});
```

At first I couldn't get the plugin script to work during debugging. Beware of extra commas after the rules! And also be advised that some copypasta tutorials contain hidden invalid characters within them! You'd never know! I had to rewrite the whole code by hand to get it to validate!

I later added nested if/else statements within the callback to call functions for all the other pages on the site which required jquery/javascript. At first I tried using a switch instead of nested if/elses, but it was not ideal. It helps to read the manual!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

#### What is your problem? Why can't you use a simple jQuery validator plugin?

Some examples:

1. [Plugins/Validation/validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate)
2. [jQuery plugin: Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)
3. [Plugins/Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't realize those existed. After googling it I feel like a moron, but there's still a problem I'm unsure about. Where and how do I implement these tools? Do I load a php file into the window which echos jquery code or do I write the jquery on my index page and try to get it to trigger after the ajax loads? I have wasted days trying to get both options to work.

Comment: I spent 4 hours going through tutorials and eventually got a static page working with the jquery validation plugin. I was pretty excited except for it's lack of support for captchas, so I copied the form from my test page into my real page and copied the jquery code for the form validation into the head of my index file. The form loads great, but, just like all the other methods I've tried, the page refreshes and wipes form data instead of proceeding with ajax updates. 

Unless there is something I'm missing, this seems like a non-solution.

Comment: Is there a live public version, which we can test, so that I can guide you?

Comment: Thanks for offering help. I did get it functioning and I posted my solution below. Best.